# Calculate the difference between datepicker date and current date in Swift2

Tags: nsdate, swift2, ios9

Hy Guys.

I'm learning swift2..

I have a datepicker element that the user enters a date. I want to calculate the difference in days, hours, minutes from the current date

I can get the date to a variable but I cannot make the difference with the current NSDate().

Any help will be appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var hourLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var dobPicker: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func convertAge(sender: AnyObject) {

        let userDOB = dobPicker.date

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMMM-yyyy"

        hourLabel.text = "\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(userDOB))"

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nowDate = NSDate()
        let df = NSDateFormatter()

        df.dateFormat = "dd-MMMM-yyyy"    

    }    

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I first calculate the difference in seconds.

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
let someDateInThePast = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-100000)
let difference = currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970 - someDateInThePast.timeIntervalSince1970
```

For the individual amount (ex. 3 days, 92 hours, 5520 minutes)

```
var days = floor(difference/24/3600)
var hours = floor(difference/3600)
var minutes = floor(difference/60)
```

For the total amount (ex. 3 days, 20 hours, 12 minutes)

```
var days = floor(difference/24/3600)
var hours = floor((difference % (24*3600) ) / 3600)
var minutes = floor((difference % 3600) / 60)
var seconds = floor(difference % 60)
```

Comment: Thank you. So I got the difference in seconds. Is there any function to convert it to hours and minutes or do I have yo make those calculations?

Comment: Do you want the difference like 3 days, 20 hours, 12 minutes? Or 3 days, 92 hours, 5520 minutes?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!